# Android discreet seekbar not showing tickmarks for max values below 2

Tags: android, seekbar

Setting the discreet seekbar attributes to **android:max="1"** does not show the tickmark on both ends of the seekbar even though its seekable.

But setting **android:max="2"** shows the three tickmarks.

How to make the tickmark appear for max value 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `AbsSeekBar`, you'll find this method:

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
protected void drawTickMarks(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mTickMark != null) {
        final int count = getMax() - getMin();
        if (count > 1) {
            final int w = mTickMark.getIntrinsicWidth();
            final int h = mTickMark.getIntrinsicHeight();
            final int halfW = w >= 0 ? w / 2 : 1;
            final int halfH = h >= 0 ? h / 2 : 1;
            mTickMark.setBounds(-halfW, -halfH, halfW, halfH);

            final float spacing = (getWidth() - mPaddingLeft - mPaddingRight) / (float) count;
            final int saveCount = canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(mPaddingLeft, getHeight() / 2);
            for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
                mTickMark.draw(canvas);
                canvas.translate(spacing, 0);
            }
            canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        }
    }
}
```

The important part is the line `if (count > 1)`; for whatever reason, the Google team decided that tick marks shouldn't be shown if there were only two selectable values.

There's no great way to work around this.

You'd have to override this entire method, but it's annotated with `@hide` which means that the outside world shouldn't know about it. This won't actually *stop* you from doing it, but it means that you always have to worry about it breaking whenever Android is updated.

The other problem is that this method uses a lot of fields that you won't have access to. You can use getters to work around that but it's a little gnarly.

Put together, you can make this class:

```
public class MySeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public MySeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void drawTickMarks(Canvas canvas) {
        if (getTickMark() != null) {
            final int count = getMax() - getMin();

            // this is the important part: you change this to 0 from 1

            if (count > 0) {
                final int w = getTickMark().getIntrinsicWidth();
                final int h = getTickMark().getIntrinsicHeight();
                final int halfW = w >= 0 ? w / 2 : 1;
                final int halfH = h >= 0 ? h / 2 : 1;
                getTickMark().setBounds(-halfW, -halfH, halfW, halfH);

                final float spacing = (getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / (float) count;
                final int saveCount = canvas.save();
                canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getHeight() / 2);
                for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
                    getTickMark().draw(canvas);
                    canvas.translate(spacing, 0);
                }
                canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```